# Click-Event with setTimeout function. Click target gets lost

Tags: javascript, onclick, settimeout, target

Calling the smoothScroll-function without setTimeout works perfectly.
As soon as i use **setTimeout** the console shows 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined'.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.heading-1');

 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    accordions[i].onclick = function () {
      setTimeout(smoothScroll, 1000);
    };
  }
  function smoothScroll(eventObj, duration) {
    var duration = 600;
    var target = eventObj.target;
```

What am I doing wrong? I only want to pass the clicked item to *smoothScroll*.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your `smoothScroll` function expects parameters, but you are not passing any. And it expects a `duration` parameter, but doesn't use it and directly creates another `duration` variable inside of it? A first step could be to fix the `onclick` handler: `function (e) { setTimeout(function() { smoothScroll(e, 600); }, 1000); }`

Comment: As you see i'm a newby in the coding-buizz ;). thank you very much for your help. i really understood what the problem was!